# xerces for read text with xml tags

Tags: xml, xerces, xerces-c

I have an XML configuration file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
<HTML_PAGE>
&lt;!doctype html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
...
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
...
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
...
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</HTML_PAGE>
```

I read with xerces the tag "HTML_PAGE". My code is like this:

```c
xercesc::DOMNode* token;
XMLCh* name = xercesc::XMLString::transcode("HTML_PAGE");
if ((token = dynamic_cast<xercesc::DOMElement*>(node)->getElementsByTagName(name)->item(item))) {
    if (token->getFirstChild()) {
        char* result = xercesc::XMLString::transcode(token->getFirstChild()->getTextContent());
    }
}
```

the string "result" take the value

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

and all works.

I want write my xml configuration file without `&lt;` and `&gt;` and if possible I want in "script" code write && and without `&amp;&amp;`

Thank you for help.

Comment: If your XML configuration file contains HTML, it will not be possible to write that unescaped (*"without `&lt;` and `&gt;`"*). HTML violates XML syntax rules, so it must be treated as a string, and that means it must be escaped. As an alternative to escaping all the special characters, which makes things harder to read, you could use a [CDATA section](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMCDATASection.html) if you want a more readable way of escaping.

Comment: But there is a caveat in picking CDATA as the escaping mechanism: Since HTML can contain CDATA sections as well, and CDATA sections cannot be nested, you must ensure that *this* HTML never contains any, or your XML will break.

Comment: The third alternative is not to use HTML at all, but XHTML. This can be a direct part of an XML document without causing any issues. If your `<HTML_PAGE>` is meant to be payload only, picking this option will cause headaches of its own.